# How to resume maven downloads

Tags: maven

I have a very slow connection, I would like to resume the downloads.

Till now I don't have any idea how to do it in the settings, I've searched on oogle for a while and nothing.

Just found another similar question in: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201011.mbox/%3C1289922369910-3267518.post@n5.nabble.com%3E .

Answer (score 2):

Resuming downloads, i.e. Range Requests [rfc7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) needs be supported by both server (Nexus, Archiva..) and client (Maven).

It's 2020 and Maven 3.6.3 looks like still doesn't support that. After internet connection is broken, it always starts downloading files from 0. In Maven logs there's info where this file is in Nexus repo. I've downloaded it using Chrome (current Nexus & Chrome support Range Requests) and saved it in correct folder in ~/.m2/repository/

Afterwards `mvn clean install` had this artifact locally, and finished correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maven will not download the artifacts it already have in local repository, unless you explicitly tell it to do it. You can just simply execute the command again.